# Fetching data from couch db database in docker using Angular 4 Application

Tags: angular, docker, couchdb, angular4-httpclient

I have a UI application which is developed in Angular 4. I also have a service Super login and database couch db. I am making a request from Angular 4 application to couch db with alias name as couchdb:5984 and the status of the request is failed (failed) net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

repo: https://github.com/janastu/iihs_couch_services

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
volumes:
couchdb_data: {}
services:
# Build the container using the client Dockerfile
client:
build: ./client
  # This line maps the contents of the client folder into the container.
ports:
  - "80:80"
links:
  - superlogin:superlogin
  - couchdb:couchdb  
couchdb:
environment:
- COUCHDB_USER:somename
 - COUCHDB_PASSWORD:somepassword
volumes:
 - ./client:/usr/src/app

# Build the container using the superlogin Dockerfile
superlogin:
build: ./superlogin>    ports:
- "3000:3000"
# Link the client container so that Nginx will have access to it
links:
- couchdb:couchdb
couchdb:
environment:
- COUCHDB_USER:somename
- COUCHDB_PASSWORD:somepassword
image: klaemo/couchdb:1.6-couchperuser
ports:
- "5984:5984"
volumes:
- "couchdb_data:/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb"
```

All the containers are up and running.
How to access the database from the container couch db from angular 4 application?

[image: Screen shot after doing docker-compose up]

Comment: Jabi, can you please post your network tab screen shots to the endpoints, i believe your DNS resolution might be failing if you are getting the error net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: The image link is here as i do not have minimum reputatation  it is not allowing me to post image. The image url is                             
        https://i.imgur.com/qY4k698.png

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the Angular application is executed in the browser, e.g. in development context using `ng serve` and accessed as `http://localhost:4200/`, correct? Your local networking does not know about the Docker service name `couchdb` - thus you should create requests to `localhost:5984` instead.

Browsers executing XHR require proper CORS headers to be set in the HTTP response of your CouchDB instance in order to perform a successful request, e.g

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS in general for information about cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) and https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html for sample configuration in nginx web server.

In case CouchDB is queried directly this needs to be enabled and configured (available since CouchDB 1.3), see http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing and https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CORS.

Example basic configuration for CouchDB's local.ini file

```
[httpd]
enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = *
```

Since your application might be target to be deployed later to some different environment, you might want to consider making the web service endpoints configurable using Angular `environments` settings - e.g. for `dev` or `prod` context.

Comment: What is the XHR require CORS headers to be set in the HTTP response?

Comment: I tried enable corns in server using ngnix configuration  but also the xhr status is failed

Comment: What's the XHR result and error message in the browser console?

Comment: Console error :http://localhost:5984/boards/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and network status is (failed) type xhr

Comment: What is `localhost:8123`? I was expecting that you call either the nginx or CouchDB server to retrieve JSON content...

Comment: Can you call the mentioned URL directly in a new browser tab?

Comment: localhost:8123?? on this port no service is running

Comment: CORS headers to be set in the HTTP response of your CouchDB instance in order to perform a successful request or for making http request to the couchdb in Headers?

Comment: CORS headers have to be defined at the endpoint that is queried - now that the Git repository is mentioned in the question I see it's CouchDB that is queried directly. Therefore, it also has to provide proper CORS headers, see http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing or e.g. https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb/blob/master/package.json for older CouchDB versions prior to v1.3.

Comment: I tried to use the docker-compose.yml from the git repo, but When requests are made to localhost:5984 the name is resolving to the host machine's couchdb instance instead of the docker container running couchdb.

Comment: @SalusSage In case you're using CouchDB on the host machine using port `5984` already, then `docker-compose up` won't start the Docker service since the port is already used (there should be an error message in the console). You can solve this by binding a different port in `docker-compose.yml` and have to adjust the Angular source code accordingly...

Comment: Ah! that makes sense, let me try with different port settings.

Comment: I tried binding a different port 8002 for couchdb, i'm not able to access it via browser when i call localhost:8002, but it works if i access 192.168.99.100:8002  That ip i got by running the command docker-machine ip